# How to add classes for target based on configuration or macros

Tags: ios, objective-c

If we have a class MyClass.h and MyClass.m and I want to include it for a specific target based on configuration. Lets say, I have a macro INCLUDE_MYCLASS for a target and those classes are two be included when this INCLUDE_MYCLASS macro is defined. How to achieve this? Or Is there a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you want not to include whole class, you can simply uncheck reference of that class from not required target.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually. It should be done through script

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Macros, you can put an if-else condition through it as well, like :

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_MYCLASS
 #import "MyClass.h"
#endif
```

This will make sure to include this class only if Macro is defined.